# mysql return different result when using view and group by

Tags: mysql

I get a wrong result when using view and group by in mysql.

A simple table `test`

```
id  name value
1   a   200
2   a   100
3   b   150
4   b   NULL
5   c   120
```

when using normal syntax as

`select * from (select * from test order by name asc, value asc ) as test group by test.name;`

it returns

```
id  name value
2   a   100
4   b   NULL
5   c   120
```

however, if a replace the subquery as a view,
it shows different results.

`create view  test_view as select * from test order by name asc, value asc;`

`select * from test_view as test group by test.name;`

it returns

```
id  name value
1   a   200
3   b   150
5   c   120
```

it really bothers me, please someone give me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and then consider rewriting your query to be deterministic. A relevant quote from the manual about what happens when you don't include all column in the group by clause: _the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause._

Answer (score 0):

Group it before and then order the result, try this, more simple same result:

```
select * from test group by name order by name asc, value asc
```

If you really need to make a subquery, it's the same, first group by:

```
select * from (select * from test group by name) as test order by test.name asc, test.value asc
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

"MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses."

There is nothing that suggests that your subquery trick should make the difference and assure the deterministic result you are hoping for.

Comment: _There is nothing that suggests that your subquery trick should make the difference and assure the deterministic result you are hoping for._ Indeed, the solution is to correct the query instead.